# SMTP Service STARTTLS Plaintext Command Injection

Tags: injection, smtp, starttls

We are getting this vulnerability on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. This vulnerability is getting triggered on port 587 for postfix. I have checked several links but I am unable to get any relevant solution for it.

Has anybody faced an issue with this vulnerability? How do I remediate this?

Links referred:

https://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/516901/30/0/threaded
https://xorl.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/cve-2011-0411-postfix-starttls-plaintext-command-injection/
http://www.postfix.org/CVE-2011-0411.html

Comment: What is reporting this vulnerability? They should have some sort of reference. Is there a CVE or any other identifier?

Comment: It was reported in the Nessus Scan and CVE is CVE-2011-2165.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the links you've provided, this appears to be CVE-2011-0411.  Given a CVE, you can browse at [suse.com](https://www.suse.com/security/cve/) to see which packages will fix it.  [In this case](https://www.suse.com/security/cve/CVE-2011-0411/), postfix >= 2.5.6-5.6.1 (patchname: slessp1-postfix) will correct the issue for SLES 11.